# SQL/PL : Как подсчитать количество записей в таблице с динамически изменяющимися условиями?

Tags: sql

Существует таблица со следующими столбцами:

- cc_num (аккаунт)
- сreate_Dttm (Время события - 'YYY/MM/DD HH:MM')

Появилась необходимость выгрузить данные по следующей логике -
Для каждого уникального аккаунта необходимо подсчитать:

- количество записей в установленный промежуток времени, к примеру
  месяц
- а также количество записей за пределами данного временного
  промежутка, если от последней записи до новой прошёл промежуток менее
  7 дней.

То есть для каждой последней строки по конкретному аккаунту, для столбца сreate_Dttm нужно увеличивать интервал "create_dttm = create_dttm + 7", до тех пор, пока записи по данному аккаунту не будут найдены.

Посчитать количество записей в интервале просто:

```
SELECT 
 acc_num,
 count(acc_num)
FROM table1 WHERE 
trunc(create_dttm) between '2019-09-01' and '2019-09-30'
GROUP BY 1
```

Но вот как в условии учесть динамическое изменение интервала? - Вероятно нужно написать функцию, которую необходимо использовать в качестве условия в самом запросе, вместо конструкции (trunc(create_dttm) between '2019-09-01' and '2019-09-30')
Но как написать данную функцию - понять не могу.

Comment: Алгоритм. Отбираем записи от начала и дальше. Добавляем вычисляемое поле, которое равно нулю если  дата меньше конца периода или если разность между текущей датой и лагом меньше недели, в противном случае поле равно единице. Далее считаем сумму с накоплением (оконную) по этому полю. И наконец оставляем только те записи, у которых эта сумма нулевая.

Comment: Спасибо! Но алгоритм мне понятен, я не понимаю как его реализовать средствами SQL/PL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Демка.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (x_date DATE)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test VALUES
> ('2019-01-01'), ('2019-01-03'), ('2019-01-05'), ('2019-01-07'),
> ('2019-01-10'), ('2019-01-15'), ('2019-01-25'), ('2019-01-27')
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 8 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> WITH
> cte1 AS ( SELECT '2019-01-04' AS d_start, '2019-01-08' AS d_end)
> ,
> cte2 AS ( SELECT x_date, COALESCE(LAG(x_date) OVER (ORDER BY x_date), x_date) lag_date
>           FROM test
>           CROSS JOIN cte1 
>           WHERE x_date >= d_start)
> ,
> cte3 AS ( SELECT x_date, CASE WHEN x_date <= d_end OR DATEDIFF(DAY, lag_date, x_date) <= 7
>                               THEN 0
>                               ELSE 1 END include 
>           FROM cte2, cte1)
> ,
> cte4 AS ( SELECT x_date, SUM(include) OVER (ORDER BY x_date) include 
>           FROM cte3 )
> SELECT x_date
> FROM cte4
> WHERE include = 0
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | x_date              |
> | :------------------ |
> | 05/01/2019 00:00:00 |
> | 07/01/2019 00:00:00 |
> | 10/01/2019 00:00:00 |
> | 15/01/2019 00:00:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c57f576450d2a12e691c696efb9e7389)*

cte1 - задаёт период

cte2 - считает лаги, а заодно отсеивает слишком ранние записи

cte3 - считает признак связности с предыдущей записью

cte4 - считает номер группы

Само собой всё это сворачивается - но для демонстрации лучше так.

Добавить дополнительный уровень группировки по аккаунту вряд ли составит проблему...